# Gain expansion in class AB power amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, power-amplifier, class-ab, class-a

Why does gain expansion occur in class AB power amplifier? I can not understand the reason by analysing circuit? Is there any physical reason? Why we can not observe this phenomenon in class A amplifier? I have previously heard about just gain compression?

I would be great if you can introduce some textbooks or article related to this subject.

Comment: http://www.av.it.pt/nbcarvalho/docs/cn4.pdf

Comment: To be honest I never heard about "gain expansion" in class AB amplifiers. Do you mean the drop in output stage voltage gain for high loads current when output transistors switch from class A to B?

Comment: Hi @G36, in class AB, Pout/Pin increase a little more than the saturation level before being saturated unlike class A amplifier that its gain just reached the saturation region. You can see AFIC10275 datasheet.

Comment: Hi @Antonio51, sorry. I can not go to the document.

Comment: Try a google search about "Gain Compression or Expansion, Distortion and
Other Large Signal Power Amplifier Related Phenomena" Perhaps limited to "countries"?